# Bindingerror in XAML and MVVM in UWP (with C#)

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I have a problem with correctly implementing a data binding with MVVM and a `ComboBox`.
I have a simple Model:

```
public class RuleSet
{
    public List<RuleMainSystem> RuleMainSystems { get; set; }

    public RuleSet()
    {
        RuleMainSystems = new List<RuleMainSystem>();
    }
}
```

And therein it looks like this:

```
public class RuleMainSystem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<RuleSubSystem> RuleSubSystems { get; set; }

    public RuleMainSystem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        RuleSubSystems = new List<RuleSubSystem>();
    }
}
```

I want now a simple binding from a page where a `ComboBox` is part of and the `ItemSource` of this `ComboBox` to be set to this `RuleSet`.
I tried to bind directly to the ViewModel, but this one is deleted from the RAM as soon as I navigate to another site and I want to avoid as much `static`'s as possible, so I created an instance of this ViewModel on the first site and give it to the second page as a parameter. That works well so far, but now I would have to bind the `ComboBox` to `this._editRulesViewModel.RuleSet.RuleMainSystems` and that's where I don't get the right code.
Maybe I approach this from the wrong side? A suggestion how I could access the data from one site to another without giving the whole instances from A to B to C and so on?
This doesn't work:
View:

```
public sealed partial class EditRules
{
    private EditRulesViewModel _editRulesViewModel;

    public EditRules()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        _editRulesViewModel = (EditRulesViewModel)e.Parameter;
    }
}
```

And in the XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MainSystemComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="_editRulesViewModel.RuleSet.RuleMainSystems" />
```

I mean, yes, the data arrives at the second page, but the `Binding` is wrong.
Oh and I also tried to set the DataContext in the XAML Page definition:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `{Binding}` does not work with `private` fields. Instead, you must expose them as `public` properties. The newer `{x:Bind}` extension does work with `public` fields, but still not with `private`.

Next - you need to use `{Binding}` syntax in all places that do data-binding - so for `ItemsSource` as well, it is not enough to write the variable name directly.

Finally, to make it all working, you will also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the page, because during `OnNavigatedTo` the data-binding has already run, so it will not bind the newly assigned value otherwise.

```
public sealed partial class EditRules : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    public EditRulesViewModel EditRulesViewModel {get; private set;}

    public EditRules()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        EditRulesViewModel = (EditRulesViewModel)e.Parameter;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.EditRulesViewModel));
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now in XAML do:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MainSystemComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    ItemsSource="{Binding EditRulesViewModel.RuleSet.RuleMainSystems}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged-Event.

Or add Elements to a list like so:

```
public sealed partial class EditRules
{
private List<object> _editRulesViewModel = new List<object>();

public EditRules()
{
    DataContext = this;
    InitializeComponent();
}

//Add nullchecking, etc.
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _editRulesViewModel.Clear();
    foreach (item in ((EditRulesViewModel)e.Parameter)RuleSet.RuleMainSystems)
    {        
        _editRulesViewModel.Add(item);
    }
}
}

<ComboBox x:Name="MainSystemComboBox" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="_editRulesViewModel" />
```